# nodejs net Socket.BytesRead does not match Buffer.ByteLength?

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, utf-8

I'm using node's Net.socket to send and receive data on a TCP connection.

Sending is fine, no issues at all.

However, my `client.on('data', data => ...` returns different things for `client.BytesRead` and `Buffer.byteLength(data, 'utf-8'))` ?

I'm transferring a bit of C# code which uses a Stream and it reads the same number of bytes given by `client.BytesRead`

Any ideas on what gives? Is node incorrectly translating the utf-8?

Also for info, the first 4 bytes the C# reads and the nodejs gets are identical, after that it goes wrong.

Here's the C#

```
byte[] payloadBytes = new byte[payloadLength];

bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesRead < payloadLength)
{
  bytesRead += stream.Read(payloadBytes, bytesRead, payloadBytes.Length - bytesRead);
}
```

and the relevant chunk of node

```
client.on('data', data => {
    console.log("------>", Buffer.byteLength(data, 'utf-8'))
    console.log("client.bytesRead", client.bytesRead)
});
```

I understand that doing a `data.length` won't give a correct answer if it's UTF-8 but I'm a bit confused.

In my case, ignoring the first 4 bytes which is correctly understood and decoded initially, I am told 308 bytes of which the first 4 are a header and discarded have been read but byte length is 549?!

Comment: without knowing the payload, it is hard to know who is right/wrong here; presumably it is a string since you are utf-8 encoding it - so: run the same string through any utf-8 encoder and see how many bytes you get?

Comment: @MarcGravell you're correct of course, I was just about to come and answer my own question. This is what bad documentation of the data gives you :D Turns out it wasn't utf-8 encoded at all despite docs to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

Just to stop future replies, it turns out the documentation I had for the data coming back was incorrect and the data was, in fact, not UTF-8 encoded.

So the code is correct but as it was trying to extract UTF-8 from a non-UTF-8 stream it resulted in some weird stuff going on.